# How to draw invisible entities (glow) with DX11?

Tags: windows, c++, game-hacking

I'm trying to understand how GLOW hacks work. In some games like CSGO you can just overwrite the memory address to 1 and glow chams are enabled. So you can see people through the walls like in this image:

[image]

But that's not learning anything new, and it's not cool. I've been reading and I understand that Present() function is hooked normally for ESP hacks to draw boxes at entity locations, but with GLOW you shouldn't hook earlier when the entity is loaded to the back buffer? And that's a game internal function or it's also in the DX11 API?

I also read about shaders, so that's why I ask here to understand the DX approach.